# Printing a timestamp with padded time values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code for my alarm clock program, which checks if the input is of the form `HH:MM:SS`.

```
def testing():
    try:
        alarm = input("> ")
        hour = int(alarm[0:2])
        minute = int(alarm[3:5])
        second = int(alarm[6:8])
        if len(alarm) == 8:
            print(("\nsets to %s:%s:%s\n" % (hour, minute, second)))
    except ValueError:
        print("format must be HH:MM:SS")
        testing()

testing()
```

It works fine unless, for example, the input is "00:00:00", in which case the output is "0:0:0" instead of the expected output with each unit padded to two digits. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the line `hour = int(alarm[0:2])` when alarm is `"00:00:00"`:

`alarm[0:2]` will be `"00"` and `int("00")` is the integer `0`.

The same happens for `minute` and `second`. When you interpolate the values of `hour`, `minute`, and `second`, then the result is `"0:0:0"`.

You can pad the hour, minute, and second values to two digits by changing your print statement to

```
print(("\nsets to %02d:%02d:%02d\n" % (hour, minute, second)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from `print(("\nsets to %s:%s:%s\n" % (hour, minute, second)))`

Into this format `print(("\nsets to %02d:%02d:%02d\n" % (hour, minute, second)))`

Now instead of printing `2:0:0 or 0:0:0` you will print `02:00:00 or 00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are formatting the values into strings, you could do without the conversion from strings to integers:

```
hour = alarm[0:2]
minute = alarm[3:5]
second = alarm[6:8]
```

Also, instead of the `%` operator, I would use [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3101) which is a more powerful string formatting method:

```
print("\nsets to {}:{}:{}\n".format(hour, minute, second))
```